# Is there "positional distinct" in XPath

Tags: xpath

Consider a query

```
//item[value='testvalue']/ancestor::container[1]
```

if *item* appears several times inside a *container* then we have several hits that supposedly should appear several times in the results. The results are nodes, right? So if I apply **distinct-values** to them they would stop being nodes and the function would technically return values losing positional information. But is there operation (refactoring, function) that allows to keep "noded" result while at the same time exclude duplicate hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there operation (refactoring, function) that allows to keep "noded"
>   result while at the same time exclude duplicate hits?

By definition the XPath operator `/` performs deduplication, therefore:

```
//item[value='testvalue']/ancestor::container[1]
```

doesn't select two identical nodes.

Comment: @Maksee: This is explicitly defined in the W3C XPath 2.0 spedification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-path-expressions (see point 1. there). In the W3 XPath 1.0 spec this isn't well-defined -- it relies on the mathematical notion of "set" -- the result of a path expression is a "node-set" which means that (as in any set) a group of identical items is represented by a single item from this group. Michael Kay explains this well in his books.

Comment: Thanks, this looks solid. Although I thought that there are cases possible when one would want to keep duplicates, for example to count items having particular ancestor. Probably it is possible with more complex predicate

Comment: A quote from the doc Dimitre mentioned "If every evaluation of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of nodes, these sequences are combined, and duplicate nodes are eliminated based on node identity. The resulting node sequence is returned in document order.
"

Comment: @Maksee: This is possible to do in XPath 2.0 but not with the `/` operator. The XPath 2.0 data model introduces the "sequence" -- by definition a sequence can contain more than one instance of the same node and nodes are in "sequence order" -- not in "document order"

Comment: But it depends how you define "duplicates". I got the impression the OP wanted deduplication by node value, not by node identity. But the question is vague, with no example input or output, so I can't really tell.